# Scala Slick: cannot find object codegen in package scala.slick.model

Tags: scala, code-generation, slick

I've created the HelloSlick 2.1 project from TypeSafe Activator, and now I'm adapting it to work with my database... There are a bunch of tables and it would be painful to define the Table classes manually, so I wanted to use the code generator.

I opened the project in Scala-Eclipse and created a new worksheet to experiment, but it gives an error in the import statement:

```
import scala.slick.model.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator`
```

errors as:

```
object codegen is not a member of package scala.slick.model
Generate.scala  /hello-slick-2.1/src/main/scala line 1  Scala Problem
```

Is there any special package to include in the classpath that is missing from the example? Am I using a wrong slick version?

Comment: I'm asking out of ignorance, can you add the slick package to the worksheet? I mean, probably in the activator template slick is specified as dependency via sbt, can you do the same in the sheet?

Comment: the Scala IDE worksheets pick the classpath from the project settings automatically :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably relying on information for Slick 2.0. In 2.1:

The code generator has been moved into a separate artifact in order to evolve it faster than Slick core. it moved from package scala.slick.model.codegen to package scala.slick.codegen. Binary compatibility will not be guaranteed, as it is supposed to be used before compile time. Add

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "2.1.0"
```

to the dependencies of your code generator sbt project.

And use package `scala.slick.codegen` rather than `scala.slick.model.codegen`.

Source: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/upgrade.html#slick-code-generator-slick-model

Comment: Thanks! I missed the upgrade guide since I'm new to slick